# How to add a popup window in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

I want to add popup window on my html page when user click add to cart button. Popupwindow need to be open only when the extra_option flag is yes. Otherwise it should just add the product into the basket (which is fine in my case).

Here is my code.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pContainer">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 wrap">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            <img src="img/delivery/products/<?=$r['ImgUrl'];?>" class="img img-responsive" style="width:auto">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pNameNdiscription">
            <h4> <b> <?=$r['ProductName']?> </b> </h4>
            <p>  <?=$r['Description']?>  </p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 wrap" style="float:right" >
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 priceWrapper">
                <h4 style="color:black" class="pPRICE">  <b> Rs. <?=$r['Price']?> </b> </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6 add2CartWrapper">

                <?php if($r['extra_option'] == 'yes') {

                // if extra_option is 'yes' when user click on 'Add To Cart' I want to show here a popup widow to select the extra option. Otherwise just add the product into the cart. 

                // I am unable to properly add a model/popup windo. 

                <input type="button" id="ad2cart" name="ad2cart" class="btn add2Cart" value="Add To Cart" onclick='updateCart("<?=$r['id']?>")'>                                    
                } 


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12"> <hr> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is here. You just need to add the code for a popup? Bootstrap has built in popups known as 'modals'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try bootstrap modal class:
The **Bootstrap Modal** is a lightweight multi-purpose JavaScript popup that is customizable and responsive. It can be used to display alert popups, videos, and images in a website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above code is from: [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

**Explanation of above code:**

1. Bootstrap has build in `modal` and `modal-dialog` class which displays popup window.
2. Further you can divide your popup window in sections. That in done in above code.
3. In above code there are three sections that are added. There are: header, body and footer.

Based on your need you can divide modal into any number of sections.

Comment: I guess you should explain your code as well rather copy paste it from somewhere else.

Comment: Sure I will add explanation. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: I tried bootstrap model, but it just add a dark screen on upper side of my page.

Comment: You need to adjust your parent div to display it on expected block of page.
Are you getting any errors on console?

Comment: I am just getting this " [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 76ms" on console when click on open model button

Comment: Which browser are you using? If chrome which version?